# Raising and lowering operators for a composite isospin $SU(2)$ system

Tags: standard-model, tensor-calculus, representation-theory, quarks, isospin-symmetry

Consider pion states composed of $q \bar q$ pairs where $q \in \left\{u,d \right\}$ transforms under an $SU(2)$ isospin flavour symmetry. These bound states transform in the tensor product $R_1 \otimes R_2$ of two representations $(R_1, R_2)$ of $SU(2)$.  Take $R_2$ as the fundamental representation of isospin with generators $I^i = \sigma^i/2$ and $R_1$ is the conjugate fundamental with generators $-(\sigma^{i})^*/2$.  If the third component of isospin is $$I_{\pm}^{R_1 \otimes R_2} = \frac{1}{2} \left( \sigma_1^{R_1 \otimes R_2} \pm i \sigma_2^{R_1 \otimes R_2}\right)$$ I can try and form a representation of this operator using the standard Pauli matrices. Take $|\pi^+ \rangle = |u\rangle |\bar d \rangle \equiv |u \rangle \otimes | \bar d \rangle \equiv |u \bar d \rangle$

Then $$I_{+}^{R_1 \otimes R_2} |u \bar d \rangle = \frac{1}{2} \left( \sigma_1^{R_1 \otimes R_2} \pm i \sigma_2^{R_1 \otimes R_2}\right)|u \bar d \rangle = \frac{1}{2}\left( \sigma_1^{R_1} |\bar d\rangle \otimes \text{Id} |u \rangle + \text{Id} |\bar d \rangle \otimes \sigma_1^{R_2} |u \rangle \pm i(1 \leftrightarrow 2)\right)$$

1)My first question is if I take $|u \rangle \rightarrow (1,0), |\bar d \rangle = (0,1)$ then I have a tensor product of the form $(2 \times 1) \otimes (2 \times 1)$ Is such a tensor product even defined?

Alternatively, I could just construct the representations for $I_{\pm}^{R_1 \otimes R_2}$ and I would end up with $4 \times 4$ matrices. But what would the $4 \times 1$ objects that these operators act on represent? Would a generic vector be something like $(u, d, \bar u, \bar d)$ so for example I would write $u = (1,0,0,0)$ and $\bar d = (0,0,0,1)$ for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that there's a confusion about how the flavour is acting. In your example $R_1 \sim \bar{\bf{2}}$ and $R_2 \sim {\bf{2}}$.
Therefore, by multiplying these representations we expect a singlet state ($\ell =0$) and a vector ($\ell =1$), i.e.,

$R_1 \otimes R_2 = \bf{1} \oplus \bf{3}$.

Now, if we identify the fundamental doublet as:
$R_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
    u  \\
    d
  \end{pmatrix}\,,
$
then
$R_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
    \bar{d} \\
    -\bar{u}
  \end{pmatrix}\,,
$ and:

$R_1\otimes R_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\bar{u}{u}+\bar{d}{d}) \oplus 
\begin{pmatrix}
    \bar{d}u \\
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\bar{d}{d}-\bar{u}{u})\\
    -\bar{u}d
  \end{pmatrix}
$

The $\pi^{\pm}$ state you are looking for is in the vector of course since it is electrically charged.

**Edit:**

Here I give the derivation based on the isospin matrices. We can define the matrix $$I_{++} =I_+\otimes I_+\,.$$ This matrix can act on the tensor product $R=R_1 \otimes R_2$ as
$$
I_{++} R =I_+ R_1 \otimes I_+ R_2=\begin{pmatrix}
    \bar{d} \\
    0
  \end{pmatrix}\otimes \begin{pmatrix}
    u\\
    0
  \end{pmatrix} \equiv |\bar{d}>|u> \equiv |\pi^+>
$$

Applying $I_{--}$ and $I_{0^+}\equiv\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} (I_{+-}+I_{-+})$ will give you exactly the vector I derived above. You can get the singlet as $I_{0^-}=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} (I_{-+}-I_{+-})$

You can represent the $I_\pm$ matrix in a reducible $4 \times 4$ form, of course, and $R$ as $4\times 1$ as
$$
I_{++}=
\begin{pmatrix}
    I_+ & 0 \\
    0& I_+
  \end{pmatrix}\,, R=\begin{pmatrix}
    R_1 \\
    R_2
  \end{pmatrix}
$$

You see that you get a natural notation with the definition of $R_1$ I used ; $I_{\pm\pm}$ gives $\pi^{\pm}$ and $I_{0^\pm}$ gives you the $\pi^0$. If you want to use instead $R_1=\begin{pmatrix}
    \bar{u} \\
    \bar{d}
  \end{pmatrix}$, you should change the definitions of the $I$s accordingly, e.g. $I_{++} \to I_{+-}$.

Comment: Hi xi45! Thanks for your response! I am just wondering why you chose $$R_1 = \begin{pmatrix} -\bar{d} \\ \bar{u} \end{pmatrix}$$- why not for example, $$R_1 = \begin{pmatrix} \bar{u} \\ \bar{d} \end{pmatrix}?$$

Comment: Hi!
Because in $SU(2)$, $\mathbf{\bar 2} \sim \epsilon {\mathbf{2}}$. Where $\epsilon$ is the anti-symmetric $2\times 2$ tensor.

Comment: There are two equivalent ways of doing the singlet contraction. This causes some confusion. In principle,  you write $R_1=\epsilon \begin{pmatrix}
    \bar u  \\
    \bar d
  \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
    -\bar d  \\
    \bar u
  \end{pmatrix}$, and you do the $SU(2)$ product: $R_1 \otimes R_2$. Or you can define $R_1 =\begin{pmatrix}
    \bar u  \\
    \bar d
  \end{pmatrix}$, but then you do the *dot* product $R_1.R_2$. Both lead to the same result because the $SU(2)$ has an $\epsilon$; for two generic doublets $v_{1,2}$, we have: $v_1 \otimes v_2 = v_1.(\epsilon.v_2)$.

Comment: Ok thanks!  Could you explain why $$\bf \bar 2 \propto \epsilon \bf 2?$$

Comment: I used $\sim$ to say : 'transforms as'. It's not a $\propto$ sign. It's a feature of  the $\mathbf{2}$ of $SU(2)$; pseudoreality, check out e.g., http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~dine/ph222/group_theory_primer.pdf

Comment: Ah I see, ok thanks! I also wondered if you had any comments regarding point 2) in my question - I have a $4 \times 4$ matrix representation for $I_+^{R_1 \otimes R_2}$. Going through with the calculation I get that $$I_+^{R_1 \otimes R_2} = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &0 &0 \\ -1& 0 &0 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ The state of greatest weight is then some $(x,y,z,w)$ such that when my matrix is applied to it, I get the zero vector. This gives the constraint $y=0, x=w$ and z arbitrary. If I set a general basis vector as $( u,d, \bar u, \bar d)$  and $x=w=1$ with $z=0$..

Comment: I get the answer $(1,0,0,1)$ which is the u dbar. But I was wondering, in light of what you have said, why is the general basis vector not $(u,d,-\bar d , \bar u)$ say?

Comment: I do not understand the method you are using, but clearly it's over-complicating a simple procedure. You're getting the correct answer either by chance, or because your method is reducible to what I described.

Comment: Ah ok. Basically what I have to do is to construct an explicit representation of $I_+^{R_1 \otimes R_2}$ using the equation I wrote in my opening post. Then using this obtain the state of greatest isospin.

Comment: Give a look to the edit.